# Write() in a file, the words occur twice

Tags: c

I am current writing a file system, and init the disk. I am trying to write into the disk block.

```
int main(){ 
    char name[] = "disk";

    create_disk(name); // fd already define in global var;
    open_disk(name);

    write(fd,"one",16);
    write(fd,"two",16);
    write(fd,"three",16);
    close(fd);
}
```

Here is the outcome in the file

```
                 IN HEX
  Offset: 00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A 0B 0C 0D 0E 0F   
00000000: 6F 6E 65 00 74 77 6F 00 74 68 72 65 65 00 00 00    one.two.three...
00000010: 74 77 6F 00 74 68 72 65 65 00 00 00 00 14 00 00    two.three.......
00000020: 74 68 72 65 65 00 00 00 00 14 00 00 00 00 00 00    three...........
00000030: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00    ................
00000040: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00    ................
```

My question: I only write `"one"`, `"two"`, `"three"` once each, why it giving me multiple copies of `"three"`, `"two"`.
How can I make my outcome looks like this?

```
one.............
two.............
three...........
................
................
```

Comment: The third argument to `write` needs to be the number of bytes to write and the buffer that you are providing needs to be at least that large. E.g. `"one"` only contains 4 bytes. So you have undefined behavior. Do you want the remaining bytes up to 16 be filled with `0x00` or what are the dots supposed to represent?

Comment: Should probably be `write(fd, "one", strlen("one"))` where obviously it would be easier to store that in a variable or array and deal with it programmatically, and/or write a `writestr()` wrapper function.

Comment: @tadman  thank you so much. it working now : >

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're writing 16 bytes from a much shorter string (i.e. reading memory you should not be). That's undefinable behavior.

Beware the nasal demons.

What you really want is something like this:

```
char buffer[16] = { 0 };
strcat(buffer, "one");
write(fd,buffer,16);
```

Now you are writing 16 chars out of a 16 char buffer which is perfectly ok.